# How much damage does a +2 Flaming dagger do?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, damage

I was allowed to buy a +2 flaming dagger in my D&D campaign, but my DM doesn't know exactly how much damage it does. He said he would try to figure out later, but I want to get ahead of the game.

How much damage does a +2 flaming dagger do?

Comment: What is your character's strength?

Answer (score 27):

## 1d4 +2 +1d6 +Strength modifier

A *+2 flaming dagger* sized for a Medium creature deals an amount of piercing or slashing damage equal to 1d4+2 plus the creature's Strength modifier. It also deals an additional 1d6 points of fire damage that is not multiplied on a critical hit.

This damage is calculated from...

1. A dagger's base damage (1d4 piercing or slashing for a Medium creature) as noted in the Equipment chapter. A dagger for a Small creature (such as a halfling) deals 1d3 points of damage instead.
2. The dagger's enhancement bonus (+2). Magic weapons add their enhancement bonuses to attack and damage rolls. This is noted in the rules for magic weapons.
3. The [*flaming* special ability](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Flaming) that adds 1d6 points of fire damage.
4. A creature adds its Strength modifier to damage rolls of melee weapons. This damage bonus is halved if the weapon is wielded using an off-hand during two-weapon fighting.

Comment: So if I had just gone for +1 flaming I would've gotten a dagger that does 1d4 (dagger dmg) + 1d6 (for flame) + 1 for modifier?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thank you. :) I Forgot to mention Thank you also Cyrad for your helpful advice.

Comment: @Jgerber click the green check mark next to the answer if you want to accept it.

Comment: @Jgerber The difference between +1 and +2 is 1 extra damage. This is about the same as changing the dagger's damage dice from 1d4 to 1d6.  In addition to that, you get +1 to hit rolls, which means you have a +5% chance of doing damage to most enemies.  (Assuming you can hit the enemy on a 19, but can't hit them on a 2)

Comment: Pedant:  Dagger's "size" is worth mentioning.

Comment: Added text about daggers sized for Small creatures.

Comment: Make a note of possible bonuses or penalties from strength into the answer

Comment: @Jgerber I know I'm being pedantic, but 1d4+2 is not really the same as making the dagger 1d6. 1d6 has a range of 1-6, while 1d4+2 has a range of 3-6. It's more like having a d6 that *never* rolls a 1 or a 2. Much better deal in my books.

Comment: @nedlud On average, an increase in die size increases the average or expected value from the die roll by half the die size increase. So 1d6 is, on average, equivalent to 1d4+1. 1d4+2 has the same average as 1d8.

Comment: @nedlud We can see this is always true because average is defined as half the sum of the minimum—which remains 1—and the maximum—which we increase. So the average is \$\frac{1+x}{2} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\$ and if we increase the die size by 2 we get \$\frac{1+(x+2)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x+2}{2}\$. The increase then is \$\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x+2}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x+2}{2} - \frac{x}{2} = \frac{x+2-x}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1\$.

Answer (score 17):

A *+2 flaming dagger*, assuming it is made for a Medium creature, has the following sources of damage:

| Damage | Damage Type<sup>2</sup> | Bonus Type<sup>1</sup> | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1d4 | piercing or slashing | — (not a bonus) | Base weapon damage |
| *variable* | *bonus*<sup>3</sup> (P or S) | — (untyped) | Strength |
| +2 | *bonus*<sup>3</sup> (P or S) | enhancement | Weapon enhancement<sup>5</sup> |
| +1d6 | fire | — (untyped) | *Flaming* special property |

These sum together to get\$^4\$ \$1\text{d}4+Str+2+1\text{d}6\$, where \$Str\$ is your Strength modifier whatever it is. Of that, \$1\text{d}4+Str+2\$ is piercing-or-slashing damage, while the final \$1\text{d}6\$ is fire damage (you may have to break it up between the damage types when dealing with damage reduction or energy resistance).

Some things to note here:

1. <sub>Bonuses can be typed or untyped. Typed bonuses do not stack with others of the same type, so the +2 enhancement bonus would not stack with other enhancement bonuses, e.g. from *greater magic weapon*.</sub>
2. <sub>Damage is also typed (and sometimes, rarely, untyped). **These are separate from bonus types, and do not affect stacking.** So if you had fire damage from some other source, it would stack with the 1d6 fire damage from *flaming*.</sub>
3. <sub>When a bonus is added to a damage roll, and no damage type is given, this number just increases the damage you are already doing, and so has the damage type of the original damage roll. Hence the +2 enhancement bonus (enhancement is a bonus type, not a damage type) as well as the bonus from Strength increase your weapon’s damage, which is piercing-or-slashing.</sub>
4. <sub>This ignores any other bonuses or penalties you may have, for example, from two-weapon fighting (halving the Strength bonus if the dagger is in your offhand) or Weapon Specialization (another +2 untyped bonus to damage, so 2 more piercing-or-slashing damage).</sub>
5. <sub>The +2 enhancement on the weapon itself not only applies a +2 enhancement bonus to its damage rolls, as indicated here, but *also* provides a +2 enhancement bonus to your attack rolls with it, as well. This is probably more valuable than the damage bonus, though to be honest neither is very valuable and optimizers usually prefer to leave enhancement bonuses at the minimum +1 and get special properties like *flaming* or *frost* instead.</sub>

Comment: Adding lines between the three rows (1d4, +2, +1d6) would make the table much easier to understand. I'd do it myself, but markdown table code is scary.

Comment: @SPavel I tried it, but it looked really cluttered and difficult to read to me. You can try it by putting `\hline` at the end of each line (after the \\\), if you’d like to play with it.